# How can I save dataset values into one local folder path

Tags: sql, console

I need to save dataset values into a local folder path.

The dataset value I'm getting is another folder path. This has to be achieved in console application.

Suppose dataset value has `c:\priyanka` path after running the console application. The data has to be populated but to a new path like `c:\Desktop`. The data from one folder path has to be copied to another folder.

How we can I achieve this?

Comment: You have to read the documentation for your dbms. The dump command should be your starting point. Also, please add dbms tag.